# Using htaccess, only allow access to the site if the url contains a query string but allow site resources (CSS, JS, etc) to work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know there are numerous questions on this, but I have yet to find one with my specific needs.  Specifically, I have a client who wants to prevent access to the site unless they have a specific string in the url as a query param.

`https://sub.domain.com/?someStringHere`

I currently have this in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^someStringHere$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.google.com/ [L,R]
```

And this works great, except for it then blocks all site resources (CSS, JS, and images) from loading, such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

If I then add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

It then allows access without the query string, so apologies if I am doing something dumb, but I am stumped.  Thank you for any help you can throw my way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following code. I just added one more rule for common assets.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^someStringHere$ [NC]
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|css|jpg|png)$ http://www.google.com/ [L,R]
```

And I can recommend you this htaccess online tester tool: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Worked like a champ and I did not know about that tool.  Very nifty!  Thank you.